# Woocommerce Back Button Not Working

Tags: wordpress, mobile, woocommerce, back-button

I'm adding code below for back button. add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'backbutton', 5); function backbutton() { echo ' Back '; }

But I'm not able to click the back button on mobile version. Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added the text 'back' not a back button. You could put in something like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'backbutton', 5); 
function backbutton() {
    echo ' <button type="button" onclick="history.back();"> Back </button> ';
}
```

This will output a back button similar to the back button in the browser.

BUT this is not good practice. If a client comes from google to the product page the clicks this back button they will go back to google, you don't want that, you want them to stay on your site. if your shop's url was `https://example.com/shop` then you could put the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'backbutton', 5); 
function backbutton() {
    echo ' <a href="https://example.com/shop"> Back to store </a> ';
}
```

Comment: How If I only want it to display on single product page but not display on the shop page?